# Facebook Logout in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, facebook, logout

I have integrated the facebook in to my application, From the FB i will be getting the userid and the name of the user and passing it to my own service that will do the validation and allows the respective user to get in to the system. I have got the userid and username from the FB and passed it my service that will do the validation,it allows the user to enter in to app, but my problem is once i logged in , how can i log out from the FB ?

Please let me know your ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on which library you use to connect to facebook.

But I guess that you have a `FBSession` class that has a `logout` method...

That `logout` method also calls `deleteFacebookCookies` that you could also directly call depending on your needs...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new facebook sdk, then us
[facebook logout:delegate]
Being facebook your Facebook object,and delegate an FBSessionDelegate.

If all goes well your delegate will be called on -(void)fbDidLogout;

Comment: yes it is ok .. fbDidLogout is calling and also logout from application/sdk but its session still in safari plugin... if I again login then it shows that already login just only confirming the permission

Answer (score 0):

If you are using old facebook sdk,then use this code for logout.make FBSession class object and code like this.     [FBSessionclassobject logout];
it will delete all FacebookCookies.